# Finding jasper server-ireport plugin.jar dependency on maven

Tags: maven, jasper-reports, ireport

I am trying to connect to the *JasperReports Server* from my Java project to get a list of all reports.

After going through the user Guide I have found that there is a ***jasperserver-ireport-plugin.jar*** which has got a lot of useful helper classes. I need to get the maven dependency for this.

Any ideas where can I find ***com-jaspersoft-ireport-jasperserver.jar*** on Maven, as I was unable to locate the dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is dependencies for *Maven* artifact:

```xml
<groupId>com.jaspersoft.jasperserver</groupId>
<artifactId>jasperserver-ireport-plugin</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>iReport Plugin</name>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.jaspersoft.jasperserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.0</version>
</parent>
.
.
.
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>iReport</groupId>
        <artifactId>iReport</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>flexdock</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexdock</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jaspersoft.jasperserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperserver-common-ws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

The [source](http://code.jaspersoft.com/svn/repos/maven2/com/jaspersoft/jasperserver/jasperserver-ireport-plugin/4.7.0/jasperserver-ireport-plugin-4.7.0.pom) for this artifact.

You can also see [JasperServer SVN Source Available](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/523938/jasperserver-svn-source-available) post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response!Really appreciate it. I tried to add them but I am getting the following error message :  Dependency com.jaspersoft.jasperserver:server4.7.0 not found. I am relatively new to all this so I am not sure why i am getting this error. Any ideas on it? Thanks

Comment: Just a note that the project I am working on has other dependencies already so I hope that's not the reason.

Comment: Did you check this artifact `com.jaspersoft.jasperserver:server4.7.0` in your local repository? Was it downloaded?

Comment: Did you add to your Maven configuration new repository (JR repository)?

Comment: @AndreasDietrich It is works for me - I've just checked it

Comment: @Alex K: sorry ... what I meant was, that at least my Eclipse `Maven Repositories` views `Refresh` and `Rebuild Index` do not work with either URLs `http://code.jaspersoft.com/svn/repos/maven2/`, `http://anonsvn:anonsvn@jasperforge.org/svn/repos/maven2`, `http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2/` and with/without the server authentication settings as also mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195128/jasper-server-maven-repository-url#comment44789774_28195519 :-( Maybe it's an Eclipse issue. Any idea?

Comment: @AndreasDietrich Try the link from my post (not from Jaspersoft community post). BTW, I send you a message via chat

Comment: @Alex K: I asked a new question that addresses this problem variant so maybe you could help with it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37962315/1915920 (some suggestions with alternative URLs from our chat I did not try yet)