# Maven Dependency Resolution Exception for jasperserver-ireport-plugin Artifact

Tags: maven, jasperserver

I have been trying to build *JasperReports* server java-webapp-sample and performed following steps:

1. cd /jasperserver/buildomatic/
2. Successfully built the jasper source.
3. To build java-webapp-sample executed `./js-ant build-sample-ws-app-ce` and stuck at a dependency conflict. Here is the log:-

build-sample-ws-app-ce:

```
 [echo] remoteDebugArg: ${remoteDebugArg}
 [echo] VERBOSE_LOGGING parameter set to: ${VERBOSE_LOGGING}
 [echo] MAVEN LOGGING: quiet
 [java] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project jasperserver-ws-sample-jar: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.jaspersoft.jasperserver:jasperserver-ws-sample-`jar:jar:5.1.0: Could not find artifact com.jaspersoft.jasperserver:jasperserver-ireport-plugin:jar:4.2.0 in js-repo-svn (file:///home/JasperWebServer/Source/jasperreports-server-cp-5.1.0-src.zip_FILES/jasperreports-server-cp-5.1.0-`src/jasperserver-repo)
```

The picture where to look for *jasperserver-ireport-plugin:jar:4.2.0.jar* is really obscure to me. How to resolve this conflict?

Comment: Did you get this artifact?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding jasper server-ireport plugin.jar dependency on maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731080/finding-jasper-server-ireport-plugin-jar-dependency-on-maven)

Comment: @AlexK : No i am not able to find this artifact. Do i need to download it? And where do i have to copy it in jasperserver directory?

Comment: Are you using maven? The artifact is [here](http://code.jaspersoft.com/svn/repos/maven2/com/jaspersoft/jasperserver/jasperserver-ireport-plugin/4.2.0/)

Comment: Did you read the [Finding jasper server-ireport plugin.jar dependency on maven](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12731080/876298) post?

Comment: Yes,I am using Maven and have gone through the related post also. But, i have two doubts :- 1. Svn repository is asking for authentication. Where to make account on it?  2. After i download the artifact, where should i copy it?

Comment: `1. Svn repository is asking for authentication. Where to make account on it? ` - anonsvn  `2. After i download the artifact, where should i copy it? ` - You can install it in your local repor, for example. You can see this post: [What is the difference between “mvn deploy” to a local repo and “mvn install”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207281/what-is-the-difference-between-mvn-deploy-to-a-local-repo-and-mvn-install) and this topic: [Installing an artifact to a specific local repository path](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html)