# Java library for JasperReports WS Client

Tags: maven, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm having trouble finding the *Java* libraries to run *JasperReports* through the Web Service interface.

These are the dependencies I'm looking for. Apparently they are not available in the central repo.

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jaspersoft.jasperserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperserver-common-ws</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jaspersoft.jasperserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperserver-ws-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jaspersoft.jasperserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperserver-ireport-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have tried adding the *JasperForge* repo to my pom:

```xml
    <repository>
        <id>JasperForge Maven Repository</id>
        <url>http://jasperforge.org/svn/repos/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
```

But that didn't work as well.

Comment: Try this: http://code.jaspersoft.com/svn/repos/maven2/   Credentials: anonsvn \ anonsvn

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding jasper server-ireport plugin.jar dependency on maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731080/finding-jasper-server-ireport-plugin-jar-dependency-on-maven)

Comment: thanks @Alex, that helped me a bit. I could find the `jasperserver-ireport-plugin` dependency. I have also found `jasperserver-common-ws:5.0.0` within my JasperServer installation directories. Now I'm only missing `jasperserver-ws-client`, I couldn't find it in the svn repo.

Answer (score -1):

- jasperserver-common-ws should be in your JRS install
- jasperserver-ireport-plugin should be in your iReports install
- jasperserver-ws-client ought to be within the jasperserver-ireport-plugin jar [reference](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/525472/java-client-ws-api-jasperserver-ws)
- The Jaserserver source code can be found at [here](http://code.jaspersoft.com/svn/repos/maven2/) (Credentials: anonsvn \ anonsvn)

Comment: Ok so I've removed `jasperserver-ws-client` from my dependencies. Now I'm getting errors because the jasperserver:server:pom:5.0.0 cannot be found: `ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.jaspersoft.jasperserver:jasperserver-common-ws:jar:5.0.0: UnresolvableModelException: Failure to find com.jaspersoft.jasperserver:server:pom:5.0.0`

Comment: Do I have to install that pom myself?