# Jasper server maven repository url?

Tags: java, maven, jasperserver

I am trying to get below dependency from jasper server.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.jaspersoft.jasperserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperserver-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But i am getting below error

```
 Missing artifact com.jaspersoft.jasperserver:jasperserver-api:jar:6.0.1
```

Here is my POM

```
<project ...>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  ....
  <name>jasperProject</name>
  <url>http://www.jaspersoft.com</url>

  <dependencies>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jaspersoft.jasperserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperserver-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Jasperserver is not free isn't it ? So it will not be available on public repository. Where are you searching this dependency, on your own repo ?

Comment: Its free as i am using jasper community edition. I am searching it under jasper repository as i mentioned  <url>http://www.jaspersoft.com</url>

Comment: just type <url> is not enough to add a repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some simple googling you can get to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731080/finding-jasper-server-ireport-plugin-jar-dependency-on-maven) on SO, where you can find a reference to [this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/523938/jasperserver-svn-source-available), which in term states you can add it like this:

```
<repository>
    <id>JasperForge Maven Repository</id>
    <!-- note: you need a <server> definition at bottom of file this file -->
    <url>http://anonsvn:anonsvn@jasperforge.org/svn/repos/maven2</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
</repository>
```

It also seems there's http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2/, which appears to be a non-browseable repository.

Comment: With url, its able to bring dependency but when i try to open jar its says "The archive is either in unknown format or damaged"

Comment: Interesting. Are you using a proxy server in between? Perhaps you need to ask the JasperSoft guys on their forum.

Comment: As far as i know , not using any proxy server, though i am not 100% sure as i am on my company network . But i dont think thats the real issue as If it would have been issue with proxy server, it should have been issue with other downloaded dependencies(dowload from project repository) . Is n't it?

Comment: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/523938/jasperserver-svn-source-available says adding element server with username and password . But as soon as i server element in pom.xml it says "Invalid element was found starting with server element" ? can i mention password in repo url?

Comment: Try adding the user password to a `<server/>` section in yout `settings.xml`.

Comment: I tried but that too does not work. Even jaspersoft guys are not replying on their forum. I don't know what to do :(

Comment: Did you try replacing the `<url/>` with `http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2/` and then keeping/removing the `<server/>` section in your `settings.xml`...?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to [put all required jars to a local maven repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html). I know this is not the best solution, but it works, when you have no idea regarding correct Jasper public repository